# Sum of divisors in Haskell

Tags: haskell, factors

I decided to write a function `divisorSum` that [sums the divisors of number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divisor_function). For instance 1, 2, 3 and 6 divide 6 evenly so:

$$ \sigma(6) = 1 + 2 + 3 + 6= 12 $$

I decided to use Euler's recurrence relation to calculate the sum of divisors:

$$\sigma(n) = \sigma(n-1) + \sigma(n-2) - \sigma(n-5) - \sigma(n-7) + \sigma(n-12) +\sigma(n-15) + \ldots$$

i.e.

$$\sigma(n) = \sum_{i\in \mathbb Z_0} (-1)^{i+1}\left( \sigma\left(n - \tfrac{3i^2-i}{2}\right) + \delta\left(n,\tfrac{3i^2-i}{2}\right)n \right)$$

(See here [for the details](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/22744/15140)). As such, I decided to export some other useful functions like `nthPentagonal` which returns the nth (generalized) pentagonal number. I created a new project with `stack new` and modified these two files:

## `src/Lib.hs`

```
module Lib
    ( nthPentagonal,
      pentagonals,
      divisorSum,
    ) where

-- | Creates a [generalized pentagonal integer]
-- | (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pentagonal_number_theorem) integer.
nthPentagonal :: Integer -> Integer
nthPentagonal n = n * (3 * n - 1) `div` 2

-- | Creates a lazy list of all the pentagonal numbers.
pentagonals :: [Integer]
pentagonals = map nthPentagonal integerStream

-- | Provides a stream for representing a bijection from naturals to integers
-- | i.e. [1, -1, 2, -2, ... ].
integerStream :: [Integer]
integerStream = map integerOrdering [1 .. ]
    where
    integerOrdering :: Integer -> Integer
    integerOrdering n
        | n `rem` 2 == 0 = (n `div` 2) * (-1)
        | otherwise = (n `div` 2) + 1

-- | Using Euler's formula for the divisor function, we see that each summand
-- | alternates between two positive and two negative. This provides a stream
-- | of 1 1 -1 -1 1 1 ... to utilze in assiting this property.
additiveStream :: [Integer]
additiveStream = map summandSign [0 .. ]
    where
    summandSign :: Integer -> Integer
    summandSign n
        | n `rem` 4 >= 2 = -1
        | otherwise = 1

-- | Kronkecker delta, return 0 if the integers are not the same, otherwise,
-- | return the value of the integer.
delta :: Integer -> Integer -> Integer
delta n i
    | n == i = n
    | otherwise = 0

-- | Calculate the sum of the divisors.
-- | Utilizes Euler's recurrence formula:
-- | $\sigma(n) = \sigma(n - 1) + \sigma(n - 2) - \sigma(n - 5) \ldots $
-- | See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/22744/15140) for more informa-
-- | tion.
divisorSum :: Integer -> Integer
divisorSum n
    | n <= 0 = 0
    | otherwise = sum $ takeWhile (/= 0)
                                  (zipWith (+)
                                           (divisorStream n)
                                           (markPentagonal n))
    where
    pentDual :: Integer -> [Integer]
    pentDual n = [ n - x | x <- pentagonals]
    divisorStream :: Integer -> [Integer]
    divisorStream n = zipWith (*)
                              (map divisorSum (pentDual n))
                              additiveStream
    markPentagonal :: Integer -> [Integer]
    markPentagonal n = zipWith (*)
                               (zipWith (delta) 
                                        pentagonals
                                        (repeat n))
                               additiveStream
```

## `app/Main.hs` (mostly just to "test" it.)

```
module Main where

import Lib

main :: IO ()
main = putStrLn $ show $ divisorSum 8
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**TL;DR:**

- use memoization to speed up calculations
- if you drive for performance use `quot` instead of `div`
- if possible, try to define your sequences without complicated functions
- use `even n` instead of `` n `rem` 2 == 0 `` or `odd n` instead of `` n `rem` 2 == 1 ``

## Type annotations and documentation

You use both type annotations as well as documentation. Great. There are only two small drawbacks:

1. The documentation strings sometimes miss highlighting, e.g. `[1, -1, 2, -2,...]` in `pentagonals`. Cross-references would also be great, e.g. `pentagonals` could point to `nthPentagonal` in its documentation.
2. Type annotations for *workers* (the local bindings) only contribute noise, as their type will be inferred by its surrounding function's types.

For example

```
integerStream :: [Integer]
integerStream = map integerOrdering [1 .. ]
    where
    integerOrdering :: Integer -> Integer
    integerOrdering n
        | n `rem` 2 == 0 = (n `div` 2) * (-1)
        | otherwise = (n `div` 2) + 1
```

doesn't need the second type annotation:

```
integerStream :: [Integer]
integerStream = map integerOrdering [1 .. ]
    where
    integerOrdering n
        | n `rem` 2 == 0 = (n `div` 2) * (-1)
        | otherwise = (n `div` 2) + 1
```

## Convey ideas in code as direct as possible

Above, we use `` n `rem` 2 == 0 `` to check whether a number is even. However, there is already a function for that: `even`. It immediately tells us the purpose of the expression, so let's use that:

```
integerStream :: [Integer]
integerStream = map integerOrdering [1 .. ]
    where
    integerOrdering n
        | even n    = (n `div` 2) * (-1)
        | otherwise = (n `div` 2) + 1
```

## Use `quotRem` if you need both the result of `rem` and `quot`

`integerStream` is a special case, though: as we need both the reminder as well as `div`'s result, we can use `divMod` or `quotRem`, e.g.

```
integerStream :: [Integer]
integerStream = map integerOrdering [1 .. ]
    where
    integerOrdering n
        | r         = -q
        | otherwise = q + 1
       where
        (q, r) = n `quotRem` 2
```

## Use simpler code where applicable

We stay at `integerStream`. As the documentation tells us, we want to have a bijection from the sequence of natural numbers to a sequence of all integers.

While the canonical mapping is indeed

$$
f(n) = 
\begin{cases}
\frac{n-1}{2}+1& \text{if } n \text{ is odd}\\
-\frac{n}{2}& \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
$$
we don't need to use that definition in our code. Instead, we can use

$$
n_1,-n_1,n_2,-n_2,\ldots.
$$

```
integerStream :: [Integer]
integerStream = go 1
    where
      go n = n : -n : go (n + 1)
```

Or, if you don't want to write it explicitly

```
integerStream :: [Integer]
integerStream = concatMap mirror [1..]
    where
      mirror n = [n, -n]
```

Both variants have the charm that no division is necessary in the computation of your list.

### Use `cycle` for repeating lists

While the methods above arguably break down to personal preference, `additiveStream` can benefit from `cycle`:

```
additiveStream :: [Integer]
additiveStream = cycle [1, 1, -1, -1]
```

## Generalize functions where applicable

`delta` can be written for *any*  type that is an instance of `Num` an `Eq`, so lets generalize:

```
delta :: (Eq n, Num n) => n -> n -> n
delta n i
    | n == i    = n
    | otherwise = 0
```

Comment: I still need a section on memoization but I don't have any time at the moment.

Comment: It's all good. I'm looking into how memoization is typically done in Haskell and can probably implement it as an exercise. :)

Comment: @Dair [This Q&A on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3208258/memoization-in-haskell) provides a great introduction IMHO.

Answer (score -1):

I tried writing `divisorSum` in terms of `ZipList`, but it kept shrinking until that wasn't needed anymore. Which is half the point of such rewrites!

```
divisorSum :: Integer -> Integer
divisorSum n
  | n <= 0 = 0
  | otherwise = sum $ takeWhile (/= 0) $ zipWith (*) additiveStream $
      map (\x -> divisorSum (n - x) + if x == n then 1 else 0) pentagonals
```

The call tree of with what arguments `divisorSum` calls itself is going to overlap with itself. In such situations, you can trade off space for time by keeping around a data structure that remembers the result for each possible argument after it's been calculated once. The `memoize` library captures this pattern:

```
divisorSum :: Integer -> Integer
divisorSum = memoFix $ \recurse n -> if n <= 0 then 0 else
  sum $ takeWhile (/= 0) $ zipWith (*) (cycle [1, 1, -1, -1]) $
    map (\x -> recurse (n - x) + if x == n then 1 else 0) pentagonals
```

Comment: it's nigh-impossible to understand this code without expending a significant amount of mental resources. As such this refactoring is not an improvement IMO, but a step back. There may be a point regarding performance, but clarity is the deciding factor here. The compiler can do the inlining for us...

Comment: The inlining allowed fusing the `zipWith`s. I think that's an improvement. Do the additional names aid your understanding? They are mere arcane symbols to me. If you find it easier to parse short definitions, simply read the code up to one `$` at a time, and pretend for the time being that the remainder is an argument - that's why it's structured that way.